# When to use commas after name and description of a person?

Tags: commas

- My best friend is Florian, an old school friend.
- I was still going out with Jame when I met my husband, Ben.

May I use commas like that?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the use of commas there. But there are certainly other ways of phrasing the same sentences, and which construction to use is one of style and personal preference. What are you asking specifically? Note that proofreading is off topic.

Comment: The second sentence uses a clear appositive, and this may be set off with a comma (a dash adds a dramatic pause, brackets would be too heavy-duty in most contexts). But omitting the comma would not be wrong. Some would say this makes the appositive defining (my husband Ben rather than my late husband, Ted) but the move towards minimal punctuation has attenuated this requirement somewhat when the sense is pretty clear. // The first sentence is slightly awkward. Arguably 'an old school friend' is in apposition to 'My best friend', and 'My best friend – an old school friend – is Florian' is ...

Comment: a possible re-ordering. A comma at least is needed in the original with this example.

Comment: Yes, yo may use commas like that… and don't you think you'd find more suitable help at SE English Language Learners?